# GCP Internet Access via Cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM in GCP with Private IP address with no Public external IP. I have configured Cloud NAT to allow this VM to access the internet via Cloud NAT but unfortunately I can't access the internet.

When I checked Cloud NAT logs, I can't see any logs.

How to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Have you added route pointing 0.0.0.0/0 to NATGW in the route table associated with subnet the VM located?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the NATGW as a next hop when trying to create the route.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by adding a route rule in the VPC routing table to forward the default route to the internet gateway.